# Set collection type swift

Tags: swift, ios8

I am learning swift through Apple's documentation and  I am on the Collection Types chapter and in the Sets section.
One of the examples is this

```
var letters = Set<Character>()
```

but when I go to enter that I get this following error.

```
error: use of unresolved identifier 'Set'
 var letters = Set<Character>()
```

there was a revision on sets according to their documentation, but nothing is helping me there.

Comment: Which Xcode version you are using? Set is introduced in Swift1.2

Comment: @Amit89 im actually using SwiftStub an online compiler, im currently at work and we are all windows based here.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Native `Set` is available since Swift 1.2. Everthing points that you're using a lower version.

[Swift 1.2 and Xcode 6.3 beta](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=22)

> New native `Set` data structure — An unordered collection of unique elements that bridges with NSSet and provides value semantics like Array and Dictionary.

Comment: sounds good. How can i stay up to date on the latest versions, can you point me in the right direction kind sir! thanks.

Comment: The obvious answer would be update XCode to latest version but provided you're using an online tool, you'd have to check what it takes to use 1.2 there.